# Eigenvalues of large tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

Given $a, b \in \Bbb R$, consider the following large tridiagonal matrix

$$M := \begin{pmatrix}
        a^2 & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
        b & (a+1)^2 & b & 0 & \cdots & \\
        0 & b & (a+2)^2 & b & \cdots  \\
        \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
        \end{pmatrix}$$

What can be said about its eigenvalues? Are analytic expressions known? Or, at least, properties of the eigenvalues?

Comment: it is known that the eigenvalues of $M_n$ separate the eigenvalues of $M_{n+1};$ it easily follows from the three term recursion relation for the determinants.

Comment: @abel Thanks. What do you mean by seperation?  I am completely ignorant of this. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Posted also on MO:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233452/eigenvalues-of-large-tridiagonal-matrix I find the advice given in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) very reasonable. Of course, you might have a look at other discussions regarding ([cross-posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting)), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M_n(a,b)$ and $M_n(a,-b)$ have same real spectrum, we may assume that $b\geq 0$. Let $\lambda_n$ be the smallest eigenvalue of $M_n$. Since there exist hidden orthogonal polynomials, the real sequence $(\lambda_n)_n$ is non-increasing.

Assume that $a\geq 0$. Note that $e_1^TM_ne_1=a^2$; then $\lambda_n\leq a^2$. Denote by $B_n$ the matrix $M_n$ with a zero diagonal (only the $b$'s remain). Then $M_n\geq B_n$ and $\lambda_n\geq \inf(\text{spectrum}(B_n))\geq -2b$. Finally the sequence $(\lambda_n)_n$ converges to $\lambda\in [-2b,a^2]$.

Note that , if $\dfrac{b}{a^2}$ is small enough, then $M_n\geq 0$ and $\lambda\approx a^2$. If $a$ is fixed and $b$ tends to $+\infty$, then $\lambda\rightarrow -2b$.

Comment: What is a hidden orthogonal polynomial? Why does the hidden orthogonal polynomial lead to the real sequence $(\lambda_n)_n$ being non-increasing?

Comment: @Hans , the characteristic polynomial $P_n$ of $M_n$ satisfies a special recurrence with three terms; according to Favard's theorem (cf. wikipedia), there is a dot product for which the $(P_n)$ are orthogonal; then the roots of $P_{n+1}$ and $P_n$ are intertwined and $(\lambda_n)$ is non-increasing.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Why is it that if $a$ is fixed and $b$ tends to $+\infty$, then $\lambda\rightarrow -2b$? I suppose this is for fixed $n$. I think it may be better to say $\frac b{a^2}\to\infty$ than fix $a$. Should we not get $\lambda\to -b$ instead of $-2b$. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $M_n$ this matrix, and let's consider its characteristic polynomial $P_n := \det(XI_n-M_n)$. Expansion according to the last column yields the recurrence relation
$$
P_n = (X-(a+n)^2)P_{n-1}-b^2P_{n-2}.
$$
with initial conditions $P_0 = 1$ and $P_1 = X-a^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Can writing down recurrence relation of above matrix say anything about eigenvalues or their properties?

Comment: If you can use the recurrence relation to get information about the characteristic polynomial, you can get information about the eigenvalues. I think the polynomials might be orthogonal for some dot product according to their recurrence relation and a theorem I can't recall.

Comment: [Favard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favard%27s_theorem)?

Comment: That'd be the one, yes.

Comment: @Groovy I failed so far to get usable expression for characteristic polynomial by hand calculation due to large size of matrix. As matrix is very large, do you know any infinite matrix theorems which help to get charcteristic polynomial in usable form? At least for lowest eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about infinite matrices, so sorry. :(

Comment: @Groovy It makes two of us :-(

Comment: There are some properties of the roots of orthogonal polynomials listed here. Maybe one of them would be helpful to you? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalPolynomials.html